# @ManyToMany Hibernate only update JoinTable

Tags: java, hibernate

I have below entities and `@ManyToMany` mapping between the two.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5340562707217344212L;  
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userId;
    private String userName;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String emailId;
    private Date createdDate;
    private Byte status;
    private Date lastModifiedDate;  
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_products_mapper",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    )
    private List<Products> products = new ArrayList<Products>();

    public void addProducts(Products product){

        this.products.add(product);     
    }


@Entity
@Table(name="products")
public class Products implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1895580713896126954L;
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long productId;
    private String productName;
    private String description;
    private double minBalance;


    public Long getProductId() {
        return this.productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(Long productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return this.productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }
```

My question is  :

1)I already have these entities persisted. `(User and Products)`

2)User and Products are already exists in databasae and relation between them is `@ManyToMany`

3)I want to insert records ONLY IN JoinTable `(user_products_mapper)` since the rows are already present for User and Products.

4)One way to achieve this is to use `UNIDIRECTIONAL` mapping as I have above and just call

```
User.addProducts
```

5) Before doing this User and Products entities will be fetched like below  :

```
User user = this.userDao.findOne(userId);
        if(user == null){
            //throw exception 
        }
        Products product = this.productDao.findOne(productId);
```

6)Is there any way of doing this ?

Answer (score 3):

When using Hibernate/JPA you do not control the actual queries being run, but you are not supposed to either.

What you would do to connect a user and a product would be something like:

```
@Transactional
public void addProductToUser(final Long userId, final Long productId) {
    final User user = em.find(User.class, userId);
    final Product product = em.find(Product.class, productId);

    user.addProduct(product);
}
```

This will result in more queries than just inserting a row (since you will fetch both `Product` and `User`), but what you gain is simple and plain Java code. The cost of the extra queries in most cases is well within what is acceptable.